# CSS - Stretch A Background Image - Not Maintaining Aspect Ratio

Tags: css

How do you stretch a background image to completely fill a container without maintaining the aspect ratio like `background-size: cover`?

Answer (score 0):

**Simply apply the following CSS:**

```
#image_container {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```